# Byte to BitSet conversion

Tags: java

I'm using the following code to do the conversion:

```
public static BitSet fromByte(byte b){
    BitSet bs = new BitSet(8);
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++){  
        if ((b & (1 << i)) > 0){  
            bs.set(i);              
        }  
    } 
    int length = bs.length();

    return bs;
}
```

The output is {0, 3, 4, 5, 6}(from debugger display of the bs) - the indexes where the bits are set. I think this should represent 1001111 with length = 7, but is wrong since 1001111 is 79, not 121. Also I want the length to be 8. Basically I want a bitSet with length 8 which represents correctly any byte number. My expectation would be 01111001 and the display of the debugger to show {1,2,3,4,5,7}

Comment: {0, 3, 4, 5, 6} is 01111001, not 01001111.

Comment: please explain me how BitSet works, since I suspected that {0,3,4,5,6} represents the indexes where the bits are 1.

Comment: why not use [BitSet.ValueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#valueOf(byte[]))

Comment: I suppose 0 represent the bit nr 7.

Comment: It IS the indices where the bits are 1, but starting from the right, not from the left.

Comment: It is where it is 1. Read it from right to left.

01111001 = 0(7) 1(6) 1(5) 1(4) 1(3) 0(2) 0(1) 1(0) -> indices 0 3 4 5 6 are 1's

Comment: @Anirudh - because I use java6 . Maybe I will switch to java7, but I must see if android supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{0, 3, 4, 5, 6} is equal to :
[(2 ^ 0) | (2 ^ 3) | (2 ^ 4) | (2 ^ 5) | (2 ^ 6)](https://www.google.fr/search?q=2%5E0%2b2%5E3%2b2%5E4%2b2%5E5%2b2%5E6)

```
2^0 = 00000001
2^3 = 00001000
2^4 = 00010000
2^5 = 00100000
2^6 = 01000000
--------------
      01111001
```

Like you guessed, 0 is also the indice of a bit equals to 1. But the bits are ordered from right to left.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to get the value represented by the bits [1..4] from a byte value (where 0 bit is the MSB - most signifiant bit). Those 5 bits represent some codec used in AMR audio frame header. But I do not know where the MSB is located.  01111001 - is in right or in the left? Those 4 bits should be 1111 or 1001.

Comment: @AlexandruCircus More likely in the left part.

Answer (score 2):

Bits in a byte are numbered right-to-left, not left-to-right. That's why setting bits `{0, 3, 4, 5, 6}` defines this pattern:

```
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the bits in this order:

```
00000001 = index 0
00000010 = index 1
00000100 = index 2
00001000 = index 3
etc.
```

i.e. from right to left, and storing them from left-to-right in the bit set.

Answer (score 1):

The length of the bitset will be as few as bits as necessary to represent the bits you have set.  For instance if you set the first three bits, the length will be 2, as only 2 bits are necessary for representation.

The constructor of the BitSet sets its **Size**, not its **length**.  I suspect they are 2 different concepts.

When I run your code, I get the result I expect.  Are you sure of the value you are passing in?  Perhaps you are confused about the **endianess** of your bits?  Usually its read from right to left, not left to right (or **big endian bitwise order**)

Comment: the 'endianess' was the problem. I though the first bit(from the left)is the MSB, like in Big Endian. I'm a started with bits operations/representation.